# segmentation fault when using malloc and aliasing

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

The following code, which is distilled from my original code, causes segmentation fault. To farther investigation, I used a debugger and found that segmentation fault occurs at line of `*pts[i][j]=...` when i=0 and j=1.

When I replace `*pts` by `a` it works well. However, `*pts` is just an alias of `a`, so the behavior should be the same, I think. Could someone tell me why this error occurs?

```cpp
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    double*** a;
    int n = 3;
    int m = 3;
    int l = 3;

    a = (double***)malloc(n * sizeof(double**));
    double**** pts = &a;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        *pts[i] = (double**)malloc(m * sizeof(double*));
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            *pts[i][j] = (double*)malloc(l * sizeof(double));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel the need to link to the page about being a [Three Star Programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: `pts[0]` ok; `pts[1]` nope, does not exist (except for comparison purposes)

Comment: OT: regarding: `a = (double***)malloc(n * sizeof(double**));` in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and is error prone.  Suggest removing that cast.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` so both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are passed to `stderr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable subscription binds tighter than pointer dereference, so

```
*pts[i][j]
```

is parsed and executed as if you wrote

```
*(pts[i][j])
```

instead of

```
(*pts)[i][j]
```

Comment: In case there's any confustion, this also applies to `*pts[i]`, which is the same as `(*pts[i])`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to declare that `pts[i]` is the same as `*(pts + i)`, and `*pts[i]` is the same as `**(pts + i)`.

In this code, you should eighter use `pts[i]` or use `*(pts +i)` like:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    double*** a;
    int n = 3;
    int m = 3;
    int l = 3;

    a = (double***)malloc(n * sizeof(double**));
    double**** pts = &a;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        pts[i] = (double**)malloc(m * sizeof(double*)); // *(pts + i)
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++){
            pts[i][j] = (double*)malloc(l * sizeof(double)); // *(*(pts + i) + j)
        }
    }
}
```